# Ubuntu unity error after kubuntu-desktop

Tags: unity, kubuntu

After installing kubuntu-desktop, when I log into a default unity session there are some minor cosmetic errors. The drop down menus (File, Edit, etc) have black words on the black menu and the keyboard input option box on the left is now just a rectangle with a slashed circle in it. I have not noticed any other problems yet. I'm using a system76 kudu professional laptop 14.04 64-bit

Comment: I switched my appearance theme from Ambiance to Radiance and the issue where I could not read the drop down menus is no longer a problem. I would still prefer to fix the problem, even though this circumvents the issue. I also noticed that chromium seems to work with the dolphin file manager rather than nautilus when running it in the default unity.